# Images don't get saved in Ubuntu Browser

Tags: downloads, browser

I use the preinstalled Ubuntu Browser (not Firefox!) in Ubuntu Xenial Xerus 16.04 LTS. I wanted to save an image, yet it didn't save anything. How can I solve this?

Comment: Ubuntu Browser is a stripped down web browser application. Highly recommended that you use a full-featured browser like Firefox, Chrome, etc. that can do what you want.

Comment: @heynnema, but I see save image option when you right click on image..should that not work?

Comment: @George Did you make sure that the correct folder was  specified in the save dialog? I can't think of any reason to use this browser. Please enlighten me. This browser doesn't even work on my machine.

Comment: @heynnema I dont use it myself but with respect to OP I tried to replicate the issue, I can right click and see _save image_ but no folder appears after click on save. So I was wondering if your _stripped down statement_ also meant bare bone functionalities...

Comment: @George Turns out image captures are stored in **~/.cache/webbrowser-app/captures/** believe it or not. I'd call that bare bones :-)

Comment: @George as if you didn't need more proof... start `webbrowser-app` in `terminal` and see dirty :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments...

Turns out image captures are stored in `~/.cache/webbrowser-app/captures/` believe it or not.

Ubuntu Browser is a stripped down web browser application. Highly recommended that you use a full-featured browser like Firefox, Chrome, etc.